# Pass PHP variable from page to class to page

Tags: php, class, variables, scope

I have a question regarding scope in PHP

I have set a variable in one file. That file creates an instance of a class and then calls a method of that class. This method includes a separate file.  What I need to know is how can the variable in the first page be referenced in the second page without having to pass it as a constructor variable to the class.

For example:

page_1.php

```
<?php
    $variable = "my variable";

    $myClass = new MyClass();
    $myClass->loadPage();
?>
```

MyClass.php

```
<?php
    Class MyClass
    {
        public function loadPage ()
        {
            include_once('page_2.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

page_2.php

```
<?php
    echo $variable;
?>
```

I hear that using a Global scope is frowned upon, and I am sure it is not the right thing to do to place the variable as fields in the class, especially considering there will likely be several unrelated variables in file_1.php which will need to be referenced in page_2.php. So what do I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the variable as a parameter to `loadPage()`:

```
$myClass->loadPage($variable);
```

and update the definition of `loadPage()` to accept a parameter:

```
public function loadPage ($variable)
```

When you include page_2.php you are simply inserting the code in that script into the currently-running script and scope. As a result, the code in page_2.php can simply reference `$variable` without any extra work.

Keep in mind that the same scoping rules apply here as elsewhere, so if you define a class or enclosure in page_2.php, you will have to explicitly pass $variable into those scopes to access its value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes perfect sense. The problem I have though is I will have different number of variables to pass to the class (including no variables at all) depending on which page is calling it. How would i get around that? Is there a way of telling the class method to expect zero or more variables, or would it be best to perhaps pass a single array of variables? (Seems a bit convoluted to me). What about passing references to objects to the class rather than a string variable?

Comment: Any one of those options seems reasonable. To make the parameter optional, just set a default value: `function loadpage($variable = null)` and check for its value in the function. An array will work if necessary, but I agree that it sounds a bit free-form and potentially messy. I like the idea of passing an object to the method as a parameter. That will provide structure to the incoming data, but allow you to include or exclude details as needed.

Comment: Thanks again George.  Very helpful